# Questions about a function with $f(0)=0$ and a bounded derivative

Tags: analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable with $f(0)=0$. If $1<f'(x)<2$  for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ .
Then which of the following statements is true on $(0,\infty)$:

A) $f$ is unbounded 
B) $f$ is increasing and bounded 
C) $f$ has at least one zero 
D) $f$ is periodic.

Comment: Eariler comment was incorrect. Now, the function is unbounded, as $f(x) \geq x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Can u justify It more

Comment: Justification is in the answer below.

Comment: If you don't show us what you have attempted, your question will be closed, sooner or later. Besides, in not-SMS English "u" is "you". Please be correct with us.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $f$ is unbounded. Assume $M>0$ is a bound for $f$, Then the MVT tells us that  for some $\xi$ with $0<\xi<M+1$, we have $f(M+1)=(M+1)f'(\xi)>M+1$, contradiction. So A is correct

As the example $f(x)=\frac32x$ shows, B, C, D are incorrect.

Comment: Isn't C correct since f has a zero at zero?

Comment: The interval considered is $(0,\infty)$ which excludes $0$.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part of the question.